# parse urls in Backbone.js

Tags: json, parsing, url, backbone.js

I am new to Backbones.js, and I was trying to get my JSON urls and parse them correctly.

This is my code:

```
window.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function(options) {
    this.id = options.id;
},
url: function() {
    return 'api/get_post/?post_type=movies&id=' + this.id;
},
parse : function(response) {
    return response.posts;
},
});

window.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: Post,
defaults: {
   model: Post,
},
url: "api/get_recent_posts/?post_type=movies",

parse : function(response) {
    return response.posts;
},

});
```

It seems that parsing for both overrides each other or something. when I remove the parse option from the Post class, I get a full response from the collection, but not from the model.

Are there any clear examples on how to set parsing for different son hierarchies? my JSON result have a status ok before it dives into the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used bones.js but maybe these examples will help.

I think what you want to do is get rid of the `parse()` function in your collection. This assumes that since it is a Post collection, your data will come in as an array of Post JSON objects `[{id:'1', 'sub':{data}},{id:'2', 'sub':{data}},{id:'3', 'sub':{data}}]` or something like that.

If your Post model has sub-models or collections, your model `parse()` will then take the sub-object property name and do something with it.

```
// In Post Model definition
parse:function(response) {
    if (response.sub) {
        // create some model or collection etc.
    }
}
```

You might have to pass an option `parse:true` when you do your collection fetch.

I posted something along these lines which might help you see how sub-models can be instantiated on fetch calls.

[Backbone.js: Load multiple collections with one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296221/backbone-js-load-multiple-collections-with-one-request/12299690#12299690)

[Cast/initialize submodels of a Backbone Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350218/cast-initialize-submodels-of-a-backbone-model/12354034#12354034)

I hope this helps.

Comment: actually, the json posts model itself is not a direct array of posts. its a json with stats, and other info.. then an array of posts within that json. i think i can get it to work by changing the parse function for the Post. The links are really helpful. thanks.